# Unity - Admob hide banner doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, hide, banner

Why doesn't my admob banner hide when I go the next scene called ''Main''?
I did everything what other people said on other threads..

This is my code:

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;  

public class AdmobAds : MonoBehaviour {

private BannerView bannerView;


    private void RequestBanner()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
        #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }

    public void HideAd()
    {
        bannerView.Destroy ();
        bannerView.Hide ();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ();
        string sceneName = currentScene.name;

        if (sceneName == "Menu") 
        {
            RequestBanner ();
        }

        else if (sceneName == "Main") 
        {
            bannerView.Destroy ();
            bannerView.Hide ();
        }
    }
}
```

Also the ''public void HideAd'' is attachted to the start button, still it doesn't hide the banner..

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `RequestBanner` function:

```
BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);
```

The `bannerView` is a local variable and the new `BannerView` instance will be stored to that local `bannerView`  variable instead of the global `bannerView`  variable.

You need that `BannerView` instance to be stored in the global `bannerView` variable.

That should be changed to:

```
bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);
```

Another problem is here:

```
public void HideAd()
{
    bannerView.Destroy ();
    bannerView.Hide ();
}
```

You are destroying `bannerView` before hiding it. It should be the other way around. You should `Hide` then `Destroy` the `bannerView`. If fact, simply Hiding the `bannerView` should be fine. You don't have to `Destroy` it.