# Unity - Admob hide banner doesn't work on real id

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, banner

First, my problem is not this:
[Unity - Admob hide banner doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576858/unity-admob-hide-banner-doesnt-work)

I'm using Admob in Unity 2018.4.2f1
My problem is, everything work great on test id, but in the real id, the **banner won't get destroyed** or **at least be hidden**.

This is my code:

```
public void HideBanner()
{
    lock (_syncRoot)
    {
        if (bannerView != null)
        {
            bannerView.Hide();
            bannerView.Destroy();
            this.BannerAdState = AdState.None;
        }
    }
}
```

My device can't test with the real AdmobID so I don't know what happened, but my client always feedbacks that the banner overdrawing the game's buttons in the **Game Result Screen**.
But I called `AdsManager.Instance.HideBanner()` when started **Game Result Screen**, and it work **fine on test id**. I don't know why it doesn't hide in the **real id**.

Thank you all.

Comment: I faced similar problem once. My problem was code sequence. Whenever the banner hiding code is called before the banner ad loaded, it won't work. So, I handed banner load event and placed banner hiding code there with check of game screen. Have you tested such scenario?

Comment: Yes I have already had the check (bool variable). When the banner is loaded, if check==false => destroy banner after one frame.